# RollbackException: caused by close() without success() on PlaceboTransaction

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

Since upgrading my Neo4j from 1.9.8 to 2.1.2. and Spring-Data from 3.2.0 to 3.2.5, I'm seeing a "RollbackException" when I attempt to call *TopLevelTransaction.close(..)*  from within a Transaction.  This does not occur if the thread doesn't already have a Transaction associated with it.

> neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:134)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:111)
>
> .... Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.rollbackCommit(TxManager.java:629)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:390)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:123)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:124)

Before the exception is thrown, the transaction was marked as "rollback only".   This occurred when I called *CreateObjectiveTxTask.createObjectiveRuleRelationships(..)*, which results in a call to *TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.chooseStrategy(..)*.

```
 private static Strategy chooseStrategy(GraphDatabase graphDatabaseService) {
    try (Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx()) {
        if (AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Indexed;
        if (SubReferenceNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.SubRef;
        if (LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Labeled;
        tx.success();
        return Strategy.Labeled;
    }
}
```

This method created a PlaceboTransaction, detected that the GraphDatabase instance is already using Index strategy, so closed the transaction without trying to call "success()" on it.

Is this likely to have caused the RollbackException?

What might cause SDN to close PlaceboTransaction before calling "success()" on it, and how can I stop SDN from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a bug in *TyperRepresentationStrategyFactory.chooseStrategy(..)*
The most recent Git commit (b40ea309) for this code moved the *tx.success()* to where it only effects a Transaction if a strategy is not already in use.

```
private static Strategy chooseStrategy(GraphDatabase graphDatabaseService) {
    Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
    try {
        if (isAlreadyIndexed(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Indexed;
        if (isAlreadySubRef(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.SubRef;
        if (isAlreadyLabeled(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Labeled;
 } finally {
        tx.success();tx.finish();
     }
```

Became

```
    try (Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx()) {
        if (AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Indexed;
        if (SubReferenceNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.SubRef;
        if (LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(graphDatabaseService)) return Strategy.Labeled;
        tx.success();
         return Strategy.Indexed;
 }
```

When I revert this change, I no longer see the RollbackException.